# How to get Simple media url from Just custom fields in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used following function to display image but it only shows id.
How do i get image/file url?

```
$id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_field_simplemedia__1509792172',true);
```

when i print **$id** means it only shows id like: **469**.
How do i get image or file url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to retrieve attached file path based on attachment ID.

```
$id = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_field_simplemedia__1509792172',true);
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
```